# How to pop an item of a list as a float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I hope this is more clear:

```
numbers = [2, 3, 2]
total = 0
while numbers:
    total += numbers.pop()
```

this will return the total valeu of numbers.

Now I must the total valeu of purchase__amount (first code) in this way (second code):

```
purchase_amount=[]
item=[]

while item != 'done':
    item=input("Enter the price, or type 'done' to finnesh ", )
    if item != 'done':
        if item.isdigit():
            purchase_amount.append(item)
        else:
            print('please type only numbers')  

print(purchase_amount)

numbers = [purchase_amount]
total = 0
while numbers:
    total += numbers.pop()
print(numbers)
```

With each atempt though I cant get the numbers from the input in the first code to become a float here and be addet in one number.

Comment: I don't see any popping going on here.

Comment: There is'nt. From this code I have to poop the itmes from purchase_amount as floads and add them in a new code.

Comment: Your answer doesn't contain enough information to reproduce the problem. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I guess that at some point you use `purchase_amount.pop` instead of `purchase_amount.pop()`, but we would need to see that code.

Comment: subtotal = 0

while purchase_amount:
    print(purchase_amount.pop)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code. One of the main issues being that `input` returns a string, not a float.

You need to cast the input value from the user. The standard way to do is like so.

```
item = input("Enter the price, or type 'done'")

if item == 'done':
    ... # Likely break from your loop

try:
    item = float(item)
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid input')
```

The second critical issue is that `numbers` is a list of list, you should use `purchase_amount` instead.

Although, poping from the list is unnecessary here as you can simply loop over it or, even better, use `sum`.

Here is a fixed version of your code.

## Fixed code

```
purchase_amount = []

while True:
    item = input("Enter the price, or type 'done'")

    if item == 'done':
        break

    try:
        purchase_amount.append(float(item))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input')

print(purchase_amount)

total = sum(purchase_amount)

print(total)
```